# Convert sequence of numbers to random-looking IDs?

Tags: random

I'm working on an application where I need to generate unique, non-sequential IDs.  One of the constraints I have is that they must consist of 3 digits followed by 2 letters (only about 600k IDs).  Given my relatively small pool of IDs I was considering simply generating all possible IDs, shuffling them and putting them into a database.  Since, internally, I'll have a simple, sequential, ID to use, it'll be easy to pluck them out one at a time & be sure I don't have any repeats.

This doesn't feel like a very satisfying solution.  Does anyone out there have a more interesting method of generating unique IDs from a limited pool than this 'lottery' method?

Comment: How many IDs do you plan on actually using?  It would be a shame to generate so many and store them only to use a few hundred for example.

Comment: why does it matter if they're sequential?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done a lot of different ways, depending on what you are trying to optimize (speed, memory usage, etc.).

ID pattern = ddd c[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)c[0]

**Option 1 (essentially like hashing, similar to Zak's):**
1 Generate a random number between 0 and number of possibilities (676k).
2- Convert number to combination

```
    ddd = random / (26^2)
    c[0] = random % (26)
    c[1] = (random / 26) % 26
```

3- Query DB for existence of ID and increment until a free one is found.

**Option 2 (Linear feedback shift register, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register)):**
1- Seed with a random number in range (0,676k).  (See below why you can't seed with '0')
2- Generate subsequent random numbers by applying the following to the current ID number

```
    num = (num >> 1) ^ (-(num & 1u) & 0x90000u);
```

3- Skip IDs larger than range (ie 0xA50A0+)
4- Convert number into ID format (as above)
*You will need to save the last number generated that was used for an ID, but you won't need to query the DB to see if it is used.  This solution will enumerate all possible IDs except [000 AA] due to the way the LFSR works.

[edit] Since your range is actually larger than you need, you can get back [000 AA] by subtracting 1 before you convert to the ID and have your valid range be (0,0xA50A0]

Comment: I'm curious.  Where did that LFSR algorithm come from?

Answer (score 5):

Use a finite group.  Basically, take a 32 or 64-bit integer, and find a large number that is coprime to the maximum value for your integer; call this number M.  Then, for all integers n, n * M will result in a unique number that has lots of digits.

This has the advantage that you don't need to pre-fill the database, or run a separate select query -- you can do this all from within one insert statement, by having your `n` just be an auto-increment, and have a separate ID column that defaults to the n * M.

Comment: actually, if you see two of these ID's side by side (or really any 3 or more at any distance) you will just be able to take the gcd of the ID's you see, and be able to exactly predict the next ID. Unfortunately, this solution would have very little entropy. Also, this doesn't conform to the 3 digit, 2 letter spec the OP used

Answer (score 4):

You could generate a random ID conforming to that standard, do a DB select to see if it exists already, then insert it into a DB to note it has been "used". For the first 25% of the life of that scheme (or about 150k entries), it should be relatively fast to generate new random ID's. After that though, it will take longer and longer, and you might as well pre-fill the table to look for free IDs.

Comment: you could encapsulate this in a stored procedure that returned an unused id. That way you're not having repeatedly hammer the database when testing ID's

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you define as sequential, you could just pick a certain starting point on the letters, such as 'aa', and just loop through the three digits, so it would be:
001aa
002aa
003aa

Once you get to zz then increment the number part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use modular arithmetic to generate ids. Pick a number that is coprime with 676,000 and for a seed. `id` is the standard incrementing id of the table. Then the following pseudocode is what you need:

```
uidNo = (id * seed) % 676000
digits = uidNo / 676
char1 = uidNo % 26
char2 = (uidNo / 26) % 26
uidCode = str(digits) + chr(char1+65) + chr(char2+65)
```

If a user has more than one consecutively issued id, they could guess the algorithm and the seed and generate all the ids in order. This may mean the algorithm is not secure enough for your use case.